# How do I fix these errors for the symfony framework demo?

Tags: php, symfony

I have symfony installed and I am currently learning it. I should also note that I am using Ubuntu 15.04 on this system.

So I ran the following command to create a demo:

```
symfony demo
```

Then I run

```
php app/console server:run
```

Which lets me run the demo. So I go to the given URL for the server. I click "browse application". The app has errors all over the place. On this page it gives me the following errors:

```
An exception occured in driver: could not find driver
500 Internal Server Error - DriverException
2 linked Exceptions: PDOException » PDOException »
[3/3] DriverException: An exception occured in driver: could not find driver   +
Logs   - 1 error
INFO - Matched route "blog_index". 
INFO - Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "AppBundle\EventListener\RedirectToPreferredLocaleListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Subscriber\SlidingPaginationSubscriber::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "CodeExplorerBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::registerCurrentController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "knp_pager.before" to listener "Knp\Component\Pager\Event\Subscriber\Sortable\SortableSubscriber::before". 
DEBUG - Notified event "knp_pager.before" to listener "Knp\Component\Pager\Event\Subscriber\Filtration\FiltrationSubscriber::before". 
DEBUG - Notified event "knp_pager.before" to listener "Knp\Component\Pager\Event\Subscriber\Paginate\PaginationSubscriber::before".
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: "An exception occured in driver: could not find driver" at /var/www/html/symfony_demo/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractSQLiteDriver.php line 85 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "AppBundle\EventListener\RedirectToPreferredLocaleListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Subscriber\SlidingPaginationSubscriber::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "CodeExplorerBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::registerCurrentController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".
```

k. I try to fix the first error, *PDOException*. I find some links. They suggest installing:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite php5-mysql
```

mysql is installed. sqlite says that it has unmet dependencies and all this stuff:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-sqlite : Depends: php5-common (= 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6) but 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: Drop the sqlite since you are using mysql: sudo apt-get install php5-mysql should do the trick.  Might need to restart your server.

Comment: Cerad, it tells me that php5-mysql is already installed. Jose, that does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I did this :

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

And it worked fine as the demo needs the sqlite driver.